# Facebook Graph App Access Token Limitations

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to build a miner to pull some statistics from public Facebook pages using Graph.  This is easy enough going through the developer documentation and generating a short-term user access token.  With the short-term user access token I am able to pull everything that I need.

Easy Problem:
I would like to get a long-term access token for obvious reasons, and I was able to do this following several other answers through this site.  So I created an app and used the app to create a 60 day user access token.  This ended up being pretty straightforward.

Harder Problem:
With this long-term user access token I am not able to pull the same public information that I could pull with my basic user access token.  For example, "category" is not available when pulling information about a public page.  Also, I cannot see the number of likes for a given public post.  I have a feeling that there is something with the App permissions but I'm not sure what I should do.

App Specifications/Information:
I added a logo, privacy policy and I have the basic permission set for e-mail, public_profile and user_friends.  I have not added a platform or any additional permissions.

I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know how to either keep my user account logged in while I make the get requests or give my app user token the permissions to mine posts on public accounts.

Comment: If category is not there it is only because you are not asking for it

Comment: You most likely used different API version (knowingly or not) for those two requests (and maybe different app ids as well.) Since API v2.4 you need to specifically ask for the fields you want, otherwise you will only get a couple of default ones returned. Go see the changelog, and the documentation chapter on basic API usage for details.